# Proper time to bevel?

Tags: modeling, geometry

I am working on a simple monitor with some thin extrusions that follow the outer rim, If I bevel first before extruding the rim I get weird geometry once I start insetting and extruding.

If I extrude the rim first I lose the ability to bevel the corners as much as I need. What is the best way to do this?

This is an add on question to 
[this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/beveled-to-early-need-to-tighten-it-up-a-little).

This is what I want
[image]

This is my bevel being restricted because the holding lines that I will eventually extrude out a little. 
[image]

This is the weird mesh I get when I bevel first and then extrude and inset to layout the screen of the monitor.

[image]

This is what the image looks like, the outer gray part is slightly extruded out.
[image]

This is the geometry of the mesh, I know its not good, hence this question.
[image]

I am just asking what is the correct way to model this so it has good topology?

Comment: "Good" topology can be tricky to define. What is good for rendering (tris) may not be good for other purposes like deforming (quads) and so on... could you define the topology you would like to achieve (a sketch would be very helpful) and specify what of your current result is not satisfiying you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to start with a plane.

I like to work with the 'Mirror Modifier' so in *Edit Mode* press <kbd>W</kbd> and Subdivide. Then select 5 vertices and hit <kbd>X</kbd> to delete them.

[image: 5 vertices]

Add a 'Mirror Modifier' and check 'Y' and 'Clipping' in the Modifier pane ('X' is checked by default).

[image: Mirror Modifier]

Add two 'Loop Cuts' by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Approximately where the monitor would be (They can be move later with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > Edge Slide). One horizontal and one vertical.

[image: Loop Cuts]

Select the corner vertex and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>V</kbd>. Adjust with mouse and roll the mouse wheel to add vertices/smooth. *Keep the number of vertices to an even number in case you want to add geometry later.*

[image: Bevel]

Select the outer vertices and press <kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to extrude scale.

[image]

---

Now you have a simple base mesh to work with. Possible result below with some additional extrusion:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so much more efficient than what I did.